# How to make the visible part of png image with transparent background as a link?

Tags: html, css

I wanted to use a .png image, with transparent background, as a link on my website.

I tried with this html:

```
<a href="index.html">
    <img border="0" src="smiley.png" alt="smiley" width="150" height="150">
</a>
```

and this css :

```
a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}
```

However, the image is still clickable on the transparent background of my image.

Here is the illustration of what I am trying to get :

[image: sample]

***Note: This picture is for illustration only. I am 100% sure that my picture has transparent background.*

**How can I use my image as a link whenever the cursor is on the smiley face only (visible part) ?**

Comment: Is the image a a smiley?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this particular image, you could use an [image map](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp) with a circle as the active area.

```
<map id="ImgMap0" name="ImgMap0">
    <area alt="" coords="30, 32, 30" href="http://www.link.com" shape="circle" />
</map>
<img src="http://placehold.it/64x64" alt="" usemap="#ImgMap0"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, but is there any other solution for this ? It would take me quite some time to create image map for 50 images.

Comment: This answer was the only thing I could think of too unless you want to server side process the images with some kind of edge detect to auto generate your image map but doing it by hand would probably be much quicker.

Answer (score 2):

Use the css-attribute `border-radius: 50%;` to curve sides (If image is circular)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this, mapping technique

```
<map name="imgmap">
<area shape="smiley" coords="x,y,radius" href="link.html" alt="img_alt">
</map>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use css3. I found this article with [details and a good example](http://www.metisonline.co.za/2012/08/responsive-css-circle-buttons/)

I did not 'hardly' test this out, but you can give it a try.

CSS

```
.circle {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #CCCCCC;
    /* some cross-browser css missing for border-radius */
    border-radius: 100px 100px 100px 100px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 200px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
}
.circle-border {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #CCCCCC;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    /* some cross-browser css missing for border-radius */
    border-radius: 100px 100px 100px 100px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 199px;
    line-height: 200px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 199px;
}
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="circle">BUTTON</a>
<hr style="clear:both;float:left;height:1px;width:100%;" />
<a href="#" class="circle-border">BUTTON</a>
```

[Re-fiddled here](http://jsfiddle.net/8jg8L/)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use an image map. I tried it with 2 `<div>`s and it worked. Just put the smiley and a `<div>` with the attribute `onclick="window.open('yoururl')"` in a main `<div>`. Make both `<div>`s round and invisible.

HTML:

```
<div id="maindiv">
<img src="smiley.png" alt="" id="smiley"/>
<div id="LinkArea" onclick="window.open('https://google.com')"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#maindiv {
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
border-radius: 100%;
z-index: 2;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
#smiley {
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
z-index: 1;
}
#LinkArea {
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
border-radius: 100%;
cursor: pointer;
z-index: 3;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
```